# Apache and LGPL differences

Tags: apache-2.0, lgpl

What is key differences between Apache and LGPL licenses?

Are they both permissive and have same level compatibility?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wikipedia has a comparision between licenses: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_and_open-source_software_licences

LGPL is not permissive, while Apache 2.0 is.

LGPL had certain things copylefted, while Apache permissive for all categories except Trade Mark grant.

LGPL copy-left categories:

- Distribution
- Modification
- Sub-licensing

LGPL linking - going with restrictions.